# How to detect that text typed in text-area is RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, right-to-left

I have a textarea in which the user can enter text in english (or any other left-to-right language) or in a language that is RTL.

When the user writes in RTL, the user must press Right-shift + ctrl in order to make the text be aligned to the right and be rtl. However, in windows (and probably other modern OSes) the user can set any key combination to switch language and text direction.

I know how to display text as RTL, but how will I know which direction to display?

Is there a way to detect that the text typed in a textarea/text-field was typed as RTL?

Comment: there are specific characters in unicode used to indicate the text direction in so called BiDi mode, but is it applicable in your case I don't know.

Comment: are those characters included in the actual text saved in the textarea?

Comment: I suppose that in most cases, UI force users to use the english alphabet when necessary, and offer specific fields in form for language specific inputs, so that no detection code is necessary.

Comment: I don't know if inputs handle that. I suppose they do if the input value contains mixed text, but otherwise I cannot tell.

Comment: you could probably setup an event handler on text change in your textarea which looks for these characters, and test it out if you have a OS supporting BiDi.

Comment: this means the textarea should be in unicode and not in utf-8 right?

Comment: utf-8 is an instance of unicode, so it should work.

Comment: see question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12006095/104380

Answer (score 44):

I've come up to a more simple and nice solution. Just add `dir="auto"` to the elements and the browser will do it's job!

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am aware of that solution, it is still quite new, and not all browsers implement it well (firefox 22 began handling it)

Comment: Thanks, good to know. It would be also nice to come up with a support table, so if someone finds one, please let me know!

Comment: you can see the summary table in http://www.w3.org/International/tests/html5/the-dir-attribute/results-dir-auto

Comment: It's not supported in IE 11

Comment: need refresh page after change language, have a solution without refresh page?

Comment: Awesome Tested in cordova apps and working like a charm

Comment: Best Answer you made my day 

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
var rtl_rx = /[\u0591-\u07FF]/;
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(){
    this.style.direction = rtl_rx.test(this.value) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
});
```

I used a simplified RegExp to detect RTL

```
/[\u0591-\u07FF]/
```

Though it will not catch each and every RTL character in the Unicode table, it probably covers all real life cases. It includes all normal Hebrew and Arabic characters, including vowelization characters.

Comment: just use dir="auto"

Answer (score 1):

You can write a quick little JavaScript/jQuery code using regular expressions. Regular expressions are limited in JavaScript though, so you will need to use the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library which has full Unicode support - if you add [the plugins](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). Then you can check the characters to see what block of Unicodes they belong to with expressions like this **\p{Hebrew}**. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Faced with the same dilemma I wrote myself a function that loops through the characters in each string and counts the number of occurrences of Hebrew characters (my site is bilingual Yiddish/English). Then the string gets a score, and an 'rtl' class is applied to the elements with a high score. You could easily add all of the RTL languages in Unicode to the for loop to make this more generic.

http://jsfiddle.net/Swyu4/9/

Please note the External Resources linking to the XRegExp libraries in the jsfiddle.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if(isRTL($(this).text()))
        $(this).addClass('rtl');
});

function isRTL(str) {
    var isHebrew = XRegExp('[\\p{Hebrew}]');
    var isLatin = XRegExp('[\\p{Latin}]');
    var partLatin = 0;
    var partHebrew = 0;
    var rtlIndex = 0;
    var isRTL = false;

    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(isLatin.test(str[i]))
            partLatin++;
        if(isHebrew.test(str[i]))
            partHebrew++;
    }
    rtlIndex = partHebrew/(partLatin + partHebrew);
    if(rtlIndex > .5) {
        isRTL = true;
    }
/*
console.log('Latin score: ' + partLatin);
console.log('Hebrew score: ' + partHebrew);
console.log('trlIndex score: ' + rtlIndex);
console.log('isRTL: ' + isRTL);
*/

    return isRTL;
}
```