# How do discover the detected text direction in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, right-to-left

`textarea` has an attribute `dir` which can accept the value `auto`. This makes the textarea automatically switch to RTL mode when the first letter is from an RTL language.

How can I get the current direction of the textarea in JS (that is  whether it is actually RTL or LTR, not 'auto') so I can handle the text differently in my code?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731909/how-to-detect-that-text-typed-in-text-area-is-rtl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that text typed in text-area is RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731909/how-to-detect-that-text-typed-in-text-area-is-rtl)